# raw_input multiple inputs around strings

Tags: python, split, raw-input

Is it possible for the user to input multiple variables around strings (so they are there as they type).
I want the user to input numbers x,y,u,v like

(x,y) to (u,v) where the brackets and commas are there to guide their input.

I hope it to be something (I know **this code is wrong**) like:

```
a1, a2, a3, a4 = raw_input("("+x1+", "+x2+") to ("+x3+", "+x4+")").split()
```

where the i'th a varaible take the value of the i'th x value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not wrong.

It actually works:

```
>>> x1,x2,x3,x4 = 'xyuv'
>>> a1, a2, a3, a4 = raw_input("("+x1+", "+x2+") to ("+x3+", "+x4+")").split()
(x, y) to (u, v)1 2 3 4
>>> a1
'1'
>>> a2
'2'
>>> a3
'3'
>>> a4
'4'
```

However:

- the output (`a1`,`a2`,`a3`,`a4`) are strings.
- it requires a strict format of 4 numbers separated by spaces. deviations from this format result in a variety of exceptions being thrown by the interpreter.

You can solve first problem with `map(int, ...)` this way:

```
a1, a2, a3, a4 = map(int, raw_input("("+x1+", "+x2+") to ("+x3+", "+x4+")").split())
```

For the second problem, maybe you can surround the code with a `try: ... except: ...`, and also surround it with a `while True` such that until it gets an exception, it repeats it:

```
while True:
    try:
        a1, a2, a3, a4 = map(int, raw_input("("+x1+", "+x2+") to ("+x3+", "+x4+")").split())
        break
    except:
        continue
```

Here I try to feed it some bad input, and finally a good input (it terminates when it gets good input):

```
(x, y) to (u, v)a
(x, y) to (u, v)a a a a
(x, y) to (u, v)1 2 3 4
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding a space after the closing bracket

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer mescalinum. It really helps but doesn't quite answer my question, the question wasn't clear. I'm trying to programme the raw_input so that (x,y) to (u,v) doesn't appear on the left (in the terminal) as the user inputs their data. Instead, for the first input, only "(" is there, then after typing x, only "(x, " is there, then after typing y only "(x,y) to (" is there etc.

Comment: that seems quite difficult to achieve with `raw_input()`: since the input it is line buffered, after every input by the user, there is going to be a newline